# Matplotlib.plot not found

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

I installed Matplotlib via Anaconda from here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/matplotlib
I used the very first command in Anaconda prompt.

But when I tried to plot from python (Spyder) as the following, I get the message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.plot'

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.plot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
```

I have installed numpy, pandas and such using the same method and they work well.
How can I fix this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: The module is called `pyplot`. Hence you need `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. It worked...! Such silly mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matplotlib.pyplot` is a state-based interface to matplotlib. `pyplot` is mainly intended for interactive plots and simple cases of programmatic plot generation. Therefore, whenever trying to work with graphs and what is commonly known and informally often referred as `matplotlib` you should `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
```